# Wireshark filter syntax

Tags: windows, networking, wireshark

I'm trying to write a filter for TShark the command line based Wireshark.
I want to add those options to the command :

```
-i 2 (interface with index n°2)
-a duration:60 (the "scan" should last 60 seconds)
-v (print the result and exit)
-x (print an ASCII dump in the file)
```

and a filter that only captures packets with these particularities :

```
"ip" (only IP packets)
"ip.src == 192.168.0.1" (source IP adress should be 192.168.0.1)
"ip.dst == 111.222.111.222" (destination IP adress should be 111.222.111.222)
"port == 80 or port == 443" (port should be http or https)
"http.request.method == 'GET'" (it should be a GET request)
```

and then I want the results to be saved in a file "test.txt".
So the final command should be this :

```
tshark -i 2 -a duration:60 -vx -f "ip" && "ip.src == 192.168.0.1" && "ip.dst == 111.222.111.222" && "port == 80 or port == 443" && "http.request.method == 'GET'" > test.txt
```

But I keep getting an error message from Windows saying that `'"ip.src == 192.168.0.1"` isn't a recognized internal or external command. I tried with spaces, without spaces ...etc, but can't figure a way to get this work.

The problem probably comes from the way I "chain" the conditions.

- Also wanted to ask if there was some kind of "stop execution" command that would stop the current capturing but still save the results in a .txt file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and a filter that only captures packets with these particularities

...

> "http.request.method == 'GET'" (it should be a GET request)

That last part is ***EXTREMELY*** difficult to do with a capture filter.  If you can avoid that, the *rest* is relatively easy to do with a capture filter:

```
"ip src 192.168.0.1 && ip dst 111.222.111.222 && (tcp port 80 or tcp port == 443)"
```

and you *might* be able to use the entire *shark filter as a *read* filter:

```
-r "ip && ip.src == 192.168.0.1 && ip.dst == 111.222.111.222 && (tcp.port == 80 or tcp.port == 443) && http.request.method == 'GET'"
```

(note that it's `tcp.port`, not just `port`).

*However*, note that for HTTP-over-SSL/TLS, if the requests are encrypted, you'll have to arrange to decrypt those in order for `http.request.method == 'GET'` to work.

(The parentheses around the "or" clauses might not be necessary, but I prefer them to just make the meaning of the expression more obvious.)

Answer (score 0):

The tshark `-f` option takes [capture filters](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureFilters), not wireshark display filters. This is the same as the [libpcap](http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/pcap-filter/) syntax.

Comment: Yes, but I need a tshark capture filter not a display display filter. So "-f" should be the right option, no ?

Comment: The specific error you're getting is caused by the `&` in your command. If you use the correct syntax you shouldn't need any `&` symbols.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `"` characters between the filter parts. Try:

```
"ip && ip.src == 192.168.0.1 && ip.dst == 111.222.111.222 &&
 port == 80 or port == 443 && http.request.method == 'GET'"
```